# How can I write JSON in file in s3 directly in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, amazon-s3, arraylist, boto3

I have data in python as `a=[{a:1,b:1},{a:3,b:3}]`. How can I write these JSON in S3 (boto3) as file directly in Python?

Comment: What have you tried already to write JSON data to S3? Where will your python code run to write the data as you may need to consider access policies as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
a=[{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":3,"b":3}]
s3.put_object(
     Body=json.dumps(a),
     Bucket='your_bucket_name',
     Key='your_key_here'
)
```

Comment: thanks, will the file contains only 
{a:1,b:1}
{a3:,b3} not the array [{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":3,"b":3}]

Comment: You can read the json and pass to body without `json.dump()` if it's already `str`

Comment: I have tried this, it is writing as array of json values, but how to append json records in a file without array? can you help me ?